# Kotlin inner class accessing outer class?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I call a method in outer class from the inner class?
I can pass it as context, but I can't call methods on it

```
    loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        ssoManager.login(emailEditText.text.toString(), passwordEditText.text.toString())
                .subscribe(object: Consumer<SSOToken> {
                    val intent = Intent(this@LoginActiviy, PasscodeActivity::class.java)
                    this@LoginActiviy.startActivity(intent)
                })
```

Comment: What's not working? this seems like it should work if your Activity is called `LoginActiviy` instead of `LoginActivity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what APIs you're using here, I'm gonna assume that your `Consumer` is `java.util.function.Consumer` for the sake of the answer.

You are writing code directly in the body of your `object`, and not inside a function. The first line of creating the `Intent` only works because you're declaring a property (and not a local variable!).

What you should do instead is implement the appropriate methods of `Consumer`, and write the code you want to execute inside there:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener {
    ssoManager.login()
            .subscribe(
                    object : Consumer<SSOToken> {
                        val foo = "bar" // this is a property of the object

                        override fun accept(t: SSOToken) {
                            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActiviy, PasscodeActivity::class.java)
                            this@LoginActiviy.startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
            )
}
```